# Yii Ajax request CSRF can not be verified

Tags: ajax, yii, csrf

I use a few different AJAX calls in one of my pages through a couple of different methods.

1. `CHtml::link()`
2. `CHtml::ajax()`
3. Within `CGridview`

Since enabling CSRF I'm having difficulty verifying the token. What is the correct way? I've read a few posts, but struggling to implement. For instance in `CHtml::link()` I've tried:

```
'data' => "Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName = Yii::app()->request->csrfToken",
```

and also within `CGridview`:

```
data: {
    Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken
},
```

Comment: Having difficulty verifying the token *when what*? What's with the `data` key you pass to `CHtml::link`? Links make GET requests and GET requests should not result in data modification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1- Fot ajax you have [ajax](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajax-detail), [ajaxLink](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxLink-detail) and [ajaxButton](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#ajaxButton-detail) not just link.

2- CSRF token works when you use POST request

3- Add CSRF token like this:`'data'`=>array('YII_CSRF_TOKEN' => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken)`

Comment: Thanks for that, any ideas for when dealing with CGridView?

Comment: `solved`. For me it was this in my function `          data: {'YII_CSRF_TOKEN' : '" . Yii::app()->request->csrfToken . "'},
`