# ajax request from a js file to yii2 controller function

Tags: php, yii2

```
function facebookAuth() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?r=account/fbauthorize',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
```

it is a simple function i wrote just to invoke the function in the controller, the GET type works fine, but the POST does not. give me this error "Bad Request (#400): Unable to verify your data submission."

it is something to do with CSRF validation in yii2, but i can't solve it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18597894/yii-ajax-request-csrf-can-not-be-verified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two important steps:

**1)** Register your js file as follows:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->homeUrl . 'js/test.js', [JqueryAsset::className()]);
```

**2)** In ajax request you need to post following value along with data:

```
yii.getCsrfParam(): yii.getCsrfToken()
```

CSRF is a security feature which can be disabled in controller, but it is not recommended.

Comment: hi, sorry for the late reply, i am not sure where to register my file. in what file i mean.

Comment: your have to rejister js on your view file and the path js/test.js have full path as webroot/yourproject/frontend/web/js/test.js in advance templet. tell me if you dont understand

Comment: thank you man i got it working since yesterday, you were of great help, thanks.

Comment: How do you print csrf in external js file?

Answer (score 0):

add this two line to your code

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
```

this will be

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?r=account/fbauthorize',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
});
```

---

**Enjoy :)**

Comment: this does not work.

and pls could u elaborate what this supposed to do?

also i stated that the GET type works fine, it is the POST type that i'm having trouble with!

Comment: read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156991/jquery-ajax-returns-400-bad-request

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the right access method.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'fbauthorize'  => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter.html